# Помогите пожалуйста найти способ сохранить ключевые слова для авторизации (JS, может и html)

Tags: javascript, html, массивы, авторизация, логин

Я только-только стал учить js, подскажите,пожалуйста.
Есть задача:
- Имеются человек 5 и у каждого из них свой личный логин (misha0003, lera997...)
-Хочется сделать так, что бы человек ввёл определённое слово, допустим misha0003, и при нажатии "Отправить" его переводило на основную страницу.
-Сделать некую базу из этих ключевых слов, которые пускают человека на основную страницу.
-Что бы эта база могла пополняться.
Теперь собственно и вопрос, какими способами это можно осуществить?
Вчера прочитал про массивы, возможно ли занести эти "Ключевые слова" в массив и что бы к нему потом можно было обращаться и проверять подходит ли введенное пользователем слово с тем, что находится в перечне разрешённых? 
Или тут нужно подключать сторонние ресурсы, например sql и прочее ? 
[image: Это изображение авторизации]

Comment: Да, вам понадобится серверный язык и база данных. А вообще если вы только-только начали учить js, то вы не тот спектр задач выбрали. Вам бы что-нибудь на особенности js и работу с DOM надо.

Comment: Что вы имеете введу под "особенностями js", если не сложно, не могли бы вы разъяснить, может есть какой-то ресурс с задачами по js ?

Comment: Особенности - асинхронные операции, замыкания, контекст выполнения функций, прототипы. Советую http://learn.javascript.ru/ из русскоязычных сайтов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да. Лучший вариант, и, пожалуй, самый верный - это использовать БД. Иначе, на локальной машине можно хранить инфу в `localStorage`. Что-то вроде 
`localStorage.setItem('login', loginValue);`
А чтобы получить инфу
`localStorage.getItem('login');`
Потом сравнивать это всё. Если только начали изучение JS, то просто учите язык. Потом разберётесь с NodeJS, mongoDB или любой другой БД и будете получать инфу оттуда.
Добавиь элемент в хранилище `localStorage.setItem('key', value);`
Получить элемент из хранилища `localStorage.getItem('key');`
Удалить элемент из хранилища `localStorage.removeItem('key');`

Comment: Почему мы не можем хранить объекты в `localStorage`?

Comment: Да. Чушь написал. Прошу прощения. Объекты можем хранить.

Comment: А ограничения есть какое-либо , ну там по кол-во или какие элементы можно хранить в нём ?

Comment: И можно ли такое проделать с массивом ? 
Допустим занести туда слова, а потом обращаться к ним?

Comment: вряд ли что то хорошее выйдет с local storage, в любом случае эти данные как то должны попасть на клиент

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko а не подскажете как положить объект в localStorage?

Comment: Так в ответе выше написано :) `localStorage.setItem('name', value);` А чтоб забрать `localStorage.getItem('name');`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ не иронизируйте. Естественно через сериализацию. JSON.stringify вполне подойдет. Что еще подсказать?)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko объект в общем случае содержит циклические ссылки

Comment: У вас в ответе не написано, как записать\считать объекты в `localStorage`.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ какой объект в общем случае содержит циклические ссылки? Интересует именно момент *в общем случае*, что означает, что объекты с циклическими ссылками встречаются\используются чаще, чем без оных. Тем более в контексте вопроса про массивы с объектами, содержащими имена\пароли.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko я именно к формулировке и докопался т.к. объект хранить нельзя, можно его сериализованн копию а это огромная разница

Comment: А я именно к формулировке **объект в общем случае** прикопался. Все-таки это не общий случай) И в контексте данной беседы можно вполне говорить про *хранить объекты в localStorage*.

Comment: @AlexSazonov добавьте код в ответ, который будет демонстрировать сохранение\получение массива в `localStorage`. Это сразу повысит ценность вашего ответа!

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko вы наверное не правильно трактуете фразу в общем случае, общий случай - это противоположность частного случая, для объекта - это все возможные по спецификации свойства, в том числе и циклические ссылки

Comment: @StrangerintheQ если трактовать в таком разрезе тогда да. В общем случае мы не можем сохранить объект в `localStorage`. И мы не можем отправить его на бакенд. В общем случае мы вообще не моем его сохранить. Если использовать нативное средство для сериализации (JSON.stringify). Таким образом, в общем случае мы никак не можем сохранять объекты.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko без специальной обработки - да, это огромная проблема на самом деле =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ добавляйте эту инфу в ответ - мы не можем сохранять объекты)) Всё - тлен.

Answer (score 1):

Если это не является средством разграничения доступа, то можно сделать все на клиенте, но что-то я сомневаюсь...

**Особенно странно выглядит предложенное решение из принятого ответа (про `localstorage`), т.к. не понятно как при наличии требования изменять список пользователей (я так полагаю централизованно) осуществлять обновление данных в Localstorage в браузерах клиентов**

Если подразумевается авторизация и разграничение доступа (т.е. пользователи не должны иметь возможность видеть данные друг друга) то для этого как минимум **пара логин-пароль**(точнее хэш от него), которые хранятся на сервере, в базе данных.

Возможен так же вариант, когда Вы доверяете проверку третьей стороне - **OAuth** (войти при помощи Google аккаунта или аккаунта соц сети)